# How to create card hover style effect like google now cards

Tags: jquery, html, css, user-interface, user-experience

How to create card hover style and possibly card load style like google now (opened in desktop browser) cards. Like this url

http://www.google.com/landing/now/#howtogetit

Comment: Show your code not URL.

Comment: I am unable to produce the exact effect like those cards in that URL. However I have come up with this. can you please suggest what to modify to make it work like google now cards.

http://jsfiddle.net/AnirbanBera/85ytzq3k/1/

Comment: Well, [`perspective`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/perspective) with the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Just wondering did they use perspective for that UI?

Comment: That will be very helpful. I am also going through the example you have provided.

Comment: Hi **michael, Opal, karthik, rayryeng, Xstian,** I see the question is 'put on hold as unclear'. Can you suggest what else needs to be done to make it proper? I'm a bit confused because people have already understood the question and posted the proper answer which indeed makes sense.

P.S : I dont have required reputation to post an image in question. otherwise I would have done so. Can you help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using `perspective` this way:

```css
body {
  background: url(http://s25.postimg.org/b6q25p4p7/black_thread.png);
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
  -webkit-perspective: 600px;
  perspective: 600px;
  text-align: center;
}
.item {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 15px;
  width: 225px;
  height: 300px;
  line-height: 300px;
  background-color: #51634b;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-animation: animOpp 0.4s 1;
  animation: animOpp 0.4s 1;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #304129;
}
.item:hover {
  -webkit-animation: anim ease-out 0.5s 1;
  animation: anim 0.5s 1;
  transform: translateZ(30px);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.item:active {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(26px);
  transform: translateZ(26px);
}
@-webkit-keyframes anim {
  0% {
    transform: rotateX(0deg) translateZ(0px);
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotateX(-4deg) translateZ(15px);
  }
  37% {
    transform: rotateX(-8deg) translateZ(30px);
    transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  }
  72% {
    transform-origin: 50% 0%;
    transform: rotateX(-4deg) translateZ(30px);
  }
  100% {
    transform-origin: 50% 0%;
    transform: rotateX(0deg) translateZ(30px);
  }
}
@keyframes anim {
  0% {
    transform: rotateX(0deg) translateZ(0px);
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotateX(-4deg) translateZ(15px);
  }
  37% {
    transform: rotateX(-8deg) translateZ(30px);
    transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  }
  72% {
    transform-origin: 50% 0%;
    transform: rotateX(-4deg) translateZ(30px);
  }
  100% {
    transform-origin: 50% 0%;
    transform: rotateX(0deg) translateZ(30px);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes animOpp {
  0% {
    transform: translateZ(30px);
  }
  35% {
    transform: translateZ(20px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateZ(0px);
  }
}
@keyframes animOpp {
  0% {
    transform: translateZ(30px);
  }
  35% {
    transform: translateZ(20px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateZ(0px);
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item">Content Goes Here</div>
    <div class="item">Content Goes Here</div>
    <div class="item">Content Goes Here</div>
    <div class="item">Content Goes Here</div>
    <div class="item">Content Goes Here</div>
    <div class="item">Content Goes Here</div>
    <div class="item">Content Goes Here</div>
    <div class="item">Content Goes Here</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: WoW! WoW!! thats what I was looking for. Thanks a lot. I cant vote it up because I dont have the required reputation (15 rep). However marked it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```css
.panel
{
    min-height:50px;
 border:1px solid;
 width:200px;
 display:inline-block;
 margin-left:10px;
 -webkit-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
 transition: 1s ease-in-out;
}

.hover-effect:hover
{
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
 -moz-transform: scale(1.3);
 -o-transform: scale(1.3);
 -ms-transform: scale(1.3);
 transform: scale(1.3);
    background-color:grey;
}
.col-xs-4{
 display:inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div class="panel panel-default hover-effect">
        card 1
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div class="panel panel-default hover-effect">
        card 2
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div class="panel panel-default hover-effect">
        card 3
        </div>
    </div>
</div



</body>
```

Comment: Hi Vrajesh, Thanks for your suggestion. But As you can see the card hover behavior (in the google now cards link) is significantly different than the one you posted. I am searching exactly like that only.

Once again thanks for your suggestion.